# Does the following polynomial has solution across all possible degrees, i.e. across all values for $T$?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that we have counts $x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{T} \sim Bin(N,p)$. Does the following polynomial has always solutions for $N$, across $T$?

$A_{2}=\prod x_{i}x_{j}$ corresponds to the product of all two pairs multiplications

$A_{3}=\prod x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}$ corresponds to the product of all three pairs multiplications

$\vdots$

$A_{T-1}=\prod x_{i}x_{j}...x_{k}$ corresponds to to the product of all $T-1$ pairs multiplications

$$N^{T}(1-(1-p)^{T})+(-1)^{T-1}N^{T-1}(\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_{t})+(-1)^{T}N^{T-2}(\sum A_{2}) +(-1)^{T} N^{T-3}(\sum A_{3})+...+(-1)^{T-1} N(\sum A_{T-1}) + (-1)^{T}\prod_{i=1}^{T}x_{i}$$

where $T$ is an integer with $T=1,2,3,...$

Also, if it has a solution can be derived in a closed form? But mainly my question is if we can always find a solution?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the significance of asking that the $x_i$ are binomially distributed? Are you asking whether, if the $x_i$ are given (maybe restricted to the interval $[0, N]$), there exists $N$ such that this expression is equal to zero?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Just wanted to give the full picture, and where are they coming from

Comment: Does that condition imply that $N$ is necessarily a non-negative integer or are you also interested in real solutions? For non-integer values of $N$ what do you mean by $x_i \sim \text{Bin}(N, p)$?

Comment: Yes exactly the $N>0$. That also the $x_{i}$ are integers. But I'm also interested in real solutions of $N$. I guess the answer that you stated proofs that, through the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've interpreted your notation correctly, this expression is

$$f(N) = \prod_{i=1}^T (N - x_i) - N^T (1 - p)^T$$

and you want to know when this polynomial has a (presumably real) root as a function of $N$, in terms of $x_i, p, T$? I still don't understand the significance of asking $x_i \sim \text{Bin}(N, p)$ but in any case a basic analysis is not difficult. Assuming $x_i \ge 0$, setting $N = \text{max}_i x_i$ gives $f(\max_i x_i) = - x_i^T (1 - p)^T \le 0$, but on the other hand the leading term of $f(N)$ is $1 - (1 - p)^T$ which is positive unless $p = 1$ or $T = 0$. So except for those degenerate cases, some real root $N \ge \max_i x_i$ exists by the intermediate value theorem.